# Can I force System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer to work non-recursively?

Tags: c#, json, system.text.json

I basically have a graph-like structure. Something like this:

```
public class Whole {
    public List<Node> allPossibleNodes = new List<Node>();
}

public class Node {
    public List<Node> neighbors = new List<Node>();
}
```

Now I want to serialize this using following code:

```
public class WriteTest {
    static JsonSerializerOptions options = new () {
        WriteIndented = true,
        IncludeFields = true,
        IgnoreReadOnlyProperties = true,
        DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull,
        ReferenceHandler = ReferenceHandler.Preserve,
    };

    public static void write() {
        var w = new Whole();
        Node? p = null; //previous
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            var n = new Node();
            w.allPossibleNodes.Add(n);
            if (p != null) {
                n.neighbors.Add(p);
                p.neighbors.Add(n);
            }
            p = n;
        }


        var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(w, options);
        File.WriteAllText("test.json", json);
    }

    public static void read() {
        var json = File.ReadAllText("test2.json");
        var w = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Whole>(json, options);
    }
}
```

It produces following output:

```
{
  "$id": "1",
  "allPossibleNodes": {
    "$id": "2",
    "$values": [
      {
        "$id": "3",
        "neighbors": {
          "$id": "4",
          "$values": [
            {
              "$id": "5",
              "neighbors": {
                "$id": "6",
                "$values": [
                  {
                    "$ref": "3"
                  },
                  {
                    "$id": "7",
                    "neighbors": {
                      "$id": "8",
                      "$values": [
                        {
                          "$ref": "5"
                        }
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "$ref": "5"
      },
      {
        "$ref": "7"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Which is problematic in that:

1. It will eventually throw me an exception:

> "JsonException: 'A possible object cycle was detected. This can either
> be due to a cycle or if the object depth is larger than the maximum
> allowed depth of 64."

or if I set `options.MaxDepth = Int.MaxValue;` it could potentially overflow the stack.

2. I't just ugly, human-non-readable garbage.

### What I would like to have is something like this:

```
{
  "$id": "1",
  "allPossibleNodes": {
    "$id": "2",
    "$values": [
      {
        "$id": "3",
        "neighbors": {
          "$id": "6",
          "$values": [
            {
                "$ref": "4"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "$id": "4",
        "neighbors": {
          "$id": "7",
          "$values": [
            {
                "$ref": "3"
            },
            {
                "$ref": "5"
            },
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "$id": "5",
        "neighbors": {
          "$id": "8",
          "$values": [
            {
                "$ref": "4"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

But unfortunately the serializer can't even read that, crying with "'Reference '4' was not found..."

Is there an option to make this work?

Comment: There is no way to do this.  System.Text.Json is a single pass serializer so it cannot look forward to resolve a reference.  What you could do is to serialize your `Whole` as a DTO in which the nodes are serialized first (without their neighbors) and then the neighbor lists are serialized separately.  Want an answer that shows that?

Comment: Do you really need the json or are you using the json to save this to disc? If the latter: LiteDB can handle this referencing through its built-in ORM. But it would be a Single File DB, not a human readable text file.

Comment: @Fildor No, I've  actually wanted to use binary serializer in the first place but after reading the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/standard/serialization/binaryformatter-security-guide (for the starters) I thought it may not be a bad idea to use the json... I just want to use this to save game states, creating save files and eventually us the same format to manage multiplayer sessions. I think I will drop the json option because I've already found couple more problems with this serializer besides the ones described in the topic...

Comment: In that case I'd really go for a single file db as an application file format. Litedb,  sqlite, something like that.

Comment: The json outputs ~700KB files while the binary serializers I've tried give me ~17-30KB for the very same data. I'm not VERY surprised but somewhat am... And the point about human-readable - yea, for me this is the only reason to choose text based formats over binary. So if the the output is not readable it just defeats the whole purpose...

Comment: @Pawulon - if file size is a problem, be sure to set `WriteIndented = false` instead of `true`.  You're taking a lot of space with whitespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do exactly what you want. System.Text.Json is a **single pass serializer** so it cannot look **forward** to resolve a reference.

As a workaround, you could disable direct serialization of `Node.neighbors` and replaces `Whole` with a [DTO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) that serializes the `allPossibleNodes` list and a table of neighbors as two separate, sequential properties.  Doing so would limit the recursion depth to something manageable.

To do this, modify `Whole` and `Node` as follows, introducing a custom converter for `Whole`:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(WholeConverter))]
public class Whole {
    public List<Node> allPossibleNodes = new List<Node>();
}

public class Node {
    [JsonIgnore]
    public List<Node> neighbors = new List<Node>();
}

class WholeConverter : JsonConverter<Whole>
{
    struct WholeDto
    {
        [JsonPropertyOrder(1)]
        public List<Node>? allPossibleNodes { get; set; }
        [JsonPropertyOrder(2)]
        public IEnumerable<NeighborItem>? neighborTable { get; set; }
    }
    
    record struct NeighborItem(Node node, List<Node> neighbors);

    public override Whole? Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        var dto = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<WholeDto>(ref reader, options);
        foreach (var item in dto.neighborTable ?? Enumerable.Empty<NeighborItem>().Where(i => i.node != null))
            item.node.neighbors = item.neighbors;
        var whole = new Whole();
        if (dto.allPossibleNodes != null)
            whole.allPossibleNodes = dto.allPossibleNodes;
        return whole;
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, Whole value, JsonSerializerOptions options) =>
        JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer,
            new WholeDto 
            { 
                allPossibleNodes = value.allPossibleNodes,
                neighborTable = value.allPossibleNodes.Where(n => n.neighbors.Count > 0).Select(n => new NeighborItem(n, n.neighbors)),
            },
            options);
}
```

The resulting JSON will look like:

```
{
  "allPossibleNodes": {
    "$id": "1",
    "$values": [
      {
        "$id": "2"
      },
      {
        "$id": "3"
      },
      {
        "$id": "4"
      }
    ]
  },
  "neighborTable": {
    "$id": "5",
    "$values": [
      {
        "node": {
          "$ref": "2"
        },
        "neighbors": {
          "$id": "6",
          "$values": [
            {
              "$ref": "3"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "node": {
          "$ref": "3"
        },
        "neighbors": {
          "$id": "7",
          "$values": [
            {
              "$ref": "2"
            },
            {
              "$ref": "4"
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "node": {
          "$ref": "4"
        },
        "neighbors": {
          "$id": "8",
          "$values": [
            {
              "$ref": "3"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

It's not quite as clean as your desired JSON, but it's still manageable.

Notes:

- The code assumes that a `Node` will only ever be serialized from with a `Whole.allPossibleNodes` list, and that this list does in fact contain all reachable nodes.

  If these assumptions are not correct, marking `neighbors` with `[JsonIgnore]` may cause problems.
- If file size is a problem, be sure to set `WriteIndented = false` instead of `true`.
- Setting `options.MaxDepth = Int.MaxValue` is no longer required.  Nodes will not be serialized recursively, so serialization depth will be capped.

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/8cs0a5).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This indeed looks better then the default output, however I don't want to use this serializer anymore... I've also posted a documentation issue/bug several days ago and didn't have any response https://github.com/dotnet/docs/issues/38575

Comment: And another problem when I used `options.MaxDepth = Int.MaxValue;` with the original method it serializes correctly but on deserialization I have "Reference 455 not  found" so it's seems like the serializer doesn't even understands itself... (Although I've checked that manually and id=455 was indeed defined in file before it was referenced, so I consider it as a bug)

Comment: *I don't want to use this serializer anymore...* -- OK.  JSON is intended for tree serialization not graph serialization so it might not be the best format for you.